# Dictionary<TKey,TValue>: exact type of TValue depends on what you put in

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

While writing some unittests, I came accros a (for me that is) weird thing.

I have a `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>`.

The test `Assert.IsType<Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>>(result)` passes.

However `Assert.IsType<IEnumerable<string>>(result["myKey"])` fails.
It should have been `System.String[]` instead.

I wrote a quick console app for verification and that even surprised me more.
The type of the value was different if I added a `string[]` or `List<string>`.

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>();
dic.Add("myArrayKey", new[] { "Value1", "Value2" });
dic.Add("myListKey", new List<string> { "Value1", "Value2" });

Console.Write("Type of dic should be Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> : ");
Console.WriteLine(dic.GetType());
Console.Write("Type of dic[myListKey] should be IEnumerable<string> : ");
Console.WriteLine(dic["myArrayKey"].GetType());
Console.Write("Type of dic[myArrayKey] should be IEnumerable<string> : ");
Console.WriteLine(dic["myListKey"].GetType());
```

Resulted in:

```
Type of dic should be Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> : System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]]
Type of dic[myArrayKey] should be IEnumerable<string> : System.String[]
Type of dic[myListKey] should be IEnumerable<string> : System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

I know that both `string[]` and `List<string>` are `IEnumerable<string>`, but the outcome is something I did not expect at all.
Can anyone give some insight in this behaviour?

On a sidenote: I changed my test from `Assert.IsType<>` to `Assert.IsAssignableFrom<>` to avoid this.

Comment: If you have an `IEnumerable<Animal>` and you put `Cat` and `Dog` types into it you wouldn't want them to change species when they came out, or to forget what species they were.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IEnumerable<string>` is just an interface `string[]` and `List<string>` implement, it is not their type.

When you get the type of an object, it gives you its exact type, not the type of the base class it inherits from or the type of an interface it implements. It can for example implement multiple interfaces.

Comment: Kicking me in the head right now... Obviously it's an interface and not a type. Guess I have to cut down work-time and get some extra sleep. Thx anyway!